# Android App Icon Resource ID of specific density

Tags: android, icons, android-resources, android-resolution, resource-id

How can I get (int) resource-id of specific density (hdpi, xhdpi, etc) of the app-icon in Android?

I know we can get drawable object of specific density using getDrawableForDensity() method, but how to get resource id of this drawable?

Comment: A given resource has the same ID for each density. That is, resource IDs don't change with density.

Comment: @MikeM. you are right and that is the problem. I need to set notification small icon and I need the resource ID for this purpose. Because some apps might use vector drawables or adaptive icons as their app icon, in that case the app crashes (RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted) if my library blindly sets the adaptive app icon as small icon for the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't need you to do this. Each device density is automatically referenced once you add the resources.
However, you should use vector drawables where necessary.